# How can i fix this heroku typescript + node.js build error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, heroku, package.json

I havent used heroku before. When I'm trying to deploy my project to heroku, i got this multiple errors in heroku logs:

`2023-02-03T09:02:57.853394+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=tech-up-api.herokuapp.com request_id=1fd2144d-0242-46b9-85f5-0212ee1d4997 fwd="31.148.135.0" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https`

my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"]
}
```

my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "tech-up-api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "./src/server.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rm -rf ./dist/ && tsc",
    "postinstall": "tsc",
    "start": "node ./src/server.ts",
    "format": "prettier --write . --ignore-path .gitignore",
    "lint": "eslint . --ignore-path .gitignore",
    "fix-style": "npm run format && npm run lint -- --fix",
    "prepare": "husky install"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": { 
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "pg": "^8.9.0",
    "pg-hstore": "^2.3.4",
    "sequelize": "^6.28.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@mate-academy/eslint-config": "0.0.20",
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.13",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.16",
    "@types/node": "^18.11.18",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.50.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.50.0",
    "eslint": "^8.33.0",
    "husky": "^8.0.3",
    "lint-staged": "^13.1.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20",
    "prettier": "2.8.3",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.ts": "npm run fix-style"
  }
}
```

[my project folders at the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRYOv.png)

I tried to change some lines in package.json & tsconfig.json but it didn't help me.

Comment: If your code compiles locally then this is more likely to be an issue with the _Heroku_ build process instead. Have you followed all of the required steps to get it up and running? I haven't used Heroku in a while but they used to require a `Proc` file, and a bundler for a successful build.

Comment: That line from your log tells us virtually nothing. Please [edit] the preceding lines into your question as well, as that's where we'll find details of what is going wrong. All contiguous error and warning lines should be included.

Answer (score -1):

WHen heroku build and starts a project, it goes looking inside an `app` folder. I had the same issue and changed my scripts in `package.json` for local and heroku...

```json
{
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node /app/dist/main-*.js",
    "start-local": "NODE_ENV=production node ./dist/main-*.js"
}
```

`outDir` - `/dist`

`start` for heroku - goes into the `app` directory and then executes node cmd

`start-local` - one that you'll your for local testing of prod build.

Comment: There is no need to use an absolute directory. In fact, that's a bad idea. The `/app` directory is an implementation detail that Heroku could change at any time.

Comment: Also, this is just a wild guess. OP has not provided any detail about what is actually happening. Please constrain your answers to things that can be reasonably inferred from the question.

Comment: @Chris isn't that the reason I wrote this answer? Also, even if absolute path is a bad idea, it still gets the app to start and run.

Comment: You're addressing a non-problem that you imagine to exist. Not only is this solution unlikely to fix anything, it introduces a bug that could blow up at any time.